# Multiple azure windows virtual machines communications

Tags: load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine, autoscaling

I need you to solve big problem of mine. I've created an IIS smooth streaming application to deliver the media content.

I'm using azure windows virtual machine, **small instance (CUP 1 Core)**, as a media server. I installed IIS Media Services on vm(Virtual Machine) and I'm creating publish points on it.

The number of users are too many and load on vm will be increase. So, I decided to go with the **Load Balancing/Auto Scaling** options. Well I'm doing this first time.

Here is my media server architecture:

I want to implement **3-tier ﻿architecture**, like I'll create 3 virtual machines and want them communicate each other to balance the load. I mean if load increase on vm-1 then load will be balance with vm-2  and/or vm-3. Also I want to auto scaling of vms.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Devendra

Answer (score 2):

to do so you can create an availability set where you can join the 3 VMs , here are some resources I think they will be very beneficial

"managing the availability of the Virtual Machines" http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/manage-vm-availability/

here is a second one for the load balancing I think it is a bit like the first one: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/

for the scaling I think it is still in the preview, you can test it by adding this feature to your account.  after that you will be able to access it in your cloud service after creating the Virtual Machines required.